# ExpressJs render after an action

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

i'm testing ExpressJs and i have a problem.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var url = require('url');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : '8889',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'test'
});

var results = '';

// INIT
exports.init = function(req, res) {
    if (req.params.query == 'names') {
        getByName(req, res);
    } else {
        res.send('Erreur');
    }
}

getByName = function(req, res) {
    currentUrl = url.parse(req.url);

    getResult = req.params.suffix.split('+');

    for (key in getResult) {
        connection.query('SELECT * from testnode WHERE nom = "'+getResult[key]+'"', function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          results += JSON.stringify(rows[0]);
          console.log(results);
        });
    }
    res.render('api', {'results' : results});
}
```

When i go for the first time on the page this one is empty and if i refresh the result appear.

I don't know why the first time the variable "results" are empty so the console.log give me the good result.

Have you got any ideas ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error comes from the mix of a loop and a callback. Node.js is a non blocking IO library : the process doesn't wait for your mysql query to finish to continue to do other stuffs, so the callback with the results is executed (sometime) after the render.

You have multiple options, the one I use is https://github.com/caolan/async or call `render` once all the callback are done.

Or change your strategy:

```js
getByName = function(req, res) {
        currentUrl = url.parse(req.url);

        getResult = req.params.suffix.split('+');

        connection.query('SELECT * from testnode WHERE nom IN ("' + getResult.join('",") + '")', function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          var results = JSON.stringify(rows); //get all the results
          res.render('api', {'results' : results});
        });
}
```